# MongoDB: Set $unset with empty parameter gives 409 error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I try to set or unset values dynamically. Mostly I have to do both, but not always. So this is what I do:

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: id }, 
    { 
        $set: data, 
        $unset: remove 
    }, 
    function (error) { 
        console.warn(error);
    }
);
```

This is working, if `data` and `remove` are set. But there isn't always something which have to be removed. So if `remove = {}`, I will get a  409 error, as `remove` is empty.

How do I have to improve the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do an extra check for the size of the `remove` object before passing it in:

```
var update = {
    $set: data
}

if (Object.keys(remove).length > 0) {
    update['$unset'] = remove;
}

Collection.update(
    { _id: id }, 
    update, 
    function (error) { 
        console.warn(error);
    }
);
```